# I can't seem to be able to access my articles through my Mediawiki wiki anymore

Tags: mediawiki

Recently I decided to create a wiki using `Mediawiki` for my personal project. Everything was working beautifully, so I tried to set up file uploads. I eventually found that I have to edit the permissions of a folder, which I attempted to do (and was unsuccessful), but since then I've been having this weird problem:

I can load my wiki page just fine, everything works until I search for an article or click the "random page" link; then, it does redirect (as in, the URL changes), but I get an error saying that localhost refused to connect.
[image: localhost refused to connect; err_connection_refused]

This doesn't happen with any other page that I didn't create myself – so all the special pages are working ok. I can also look up each article by opening any of the pages that load and then manually editing the URL to the URL of the article, which then makes it also load fine.

Then, I can follow links in that article just fine and I can edit the article too (but upon saving, I get the `localhost refused to connect` error again, even though it does actually save).

(Also, please note that I am a complete idiot who has next to no idea what he's doing, so I apologize if this has an obvious solution that I am just not seeing)

Comment: It is likely your folder permissions are wrong.  Find one file that fails, and post the paths and permissions.

Comment: Hello, so: I found someone on the internet saying they set /var/www to have permissions 777; someone said you should't do that for public sites, but I figured since my wiki is not ever going to be public, it shouldn't matter. Then, the problems started. I searched for what the default permissions for that folder are, and found 755, but when I applied that, nothing changed. I then tried various different permissions, but it either didn't help or it made the main page not work either. Yet again, sorry if I'm being really dumb